# How to Allow http in query string without using mod_security?

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form-7, mod-security

I am using contact form 7 to send an URL from one form to other using `on_sent_ok`.
Trying to send `http://myurl.com` in the query string redirects me to the 403 forbidden page. On some research, I found it a `mod_secrity` causing the issue. Can it be done without turning the `mod_security` off?

This is my code for contact

```
on_sent_ok: "location ='http://example.com/somepage/?u='+jQuery('#url').val();"
```

where `#url` is the input for the url.

More if this mod is turned off, will it be fixed as I have many sites hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) when using an complete url in query strings.

```
on_sent_ok: "location ='http://example.com/somepage/?u='+encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#url').val());"
```

Comment: Yes I checked that too but page gives same error of forbidden.

Comment: @SachinStellen Whats the resulted url?

Comment: it gives me encoded url like `http://example.com/somepage/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsomeurl.com` but the error still remains

Comment: @SachinStellen Then the problem is somewhere else in your application